Pythonの simple-salesforce で Organization ID を指定したログインができない
simple-salesforce のドキュメント には以下のような記載があります。

To login using IP-whitelist Organization ID method, simply use your Salesforce username, password and organizationId:

しかし、以下のコードではログインができません。
ログイン先の環境はサンドボックスで、ネットワークアクセスとプロファイルにIP許可をいれています。組織IDは「設定→会社情報→組織ID」から取得しています。
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce

sf = Salesforce(password='password', username='myemail@example.com', organizationId='OrgId')

しかし、organizationIdが空文字の場合、ログインができます。
これはなぜでしょうか。
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce

sf = Salesforce(password='password', username='myemail@example.com', organizationId='')


サンドボックス環境の場合には以下のような説明も書かれています。 "If you’d like to enter a sandbox, simply add domain='test' to your Salesforce() call."
